# Ping not work on STM32H745 ETH

Tags: stm32, ethernet

I'm trying to get the ethernet interface to work on an STM32H745. After fixing various hardware problems, now I don't just have software problems.

I created a simple project with CubeMX, basically I did these things:

- Enabled ethrmnet interfaces
- Set all pins related to "very high speed"
- Enabled LWIP with static IP set to 10.0.1.100/24
- Increased Heap Memory size to 10k
- Configured the MPU as in the attached document
- In the flash.ld file I added this piece:

  .lwip_sec (NOLOAD) :
  {

  . = ABSOLUTE(0x30000000);
  *(.RxDecripSection)

  . = ABSOLUTE(0x30000200);
  *(.TxDecripSection)

  } >RAM_D2

Then in the mail loop I just put this function: **MX_LWIP_Process();**

I connected an ethernet cable to the board, the link status LEDs light up well, but I can't ping the board's IP.

[image]

I think I've done a really basic setup, where could I have gone wrong?

The only doubts I have are about memory:

- have I configured the MPU correctly?
- did I modify the FLASH.ld file correctly?
- Should I somehow configure the address of the LWIP_RAM_HEAP_POINTER (RAM Heap Pointer) in the MPU or in the FLASH.ld file, if so, how?
- Am I missing any other steps to do? Something to change in my configuration?

I saw that there are many many posts on this topic, I have read many but I haven't been able to solve the problem yet.

Comment: How do you ping it? Has your computer been set up to the same IP range, what are the computer IP settings?

Comment: All of my internal LAN devices connected to my router have addresses in the 192.168.0.x.  Do you have a router/modem? What's on the other side of the ethernet cable you connected to the board?

Comment: Yes, the computer has a compatible IP and between the PC and my board there is only a simple desk ethernet switch.